# Why am I getting a reference error between my JS classes?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to invoke the `averageScore()` function that's declared in my `Player` class from within my `Leaderboard` class, but I'm getting a reference error.

Dropping the code in my `Player` class into the console works fine, but when I try to call it from `Leaderboard` I get a `Reference error: add_score is undefined`.

Here's my player class:

```
class Player {

  constructor(player_id, score) {
   this.player_id = player_id;
   this.scores = [score];
   this.total = score;
   //this.average = this.total/this.scores.length;
    }

  addScore(score) {
    this.total += score;
    this.scores.push(score);
    return score;
  }

  averageScore() {
    return this.scores.length ? this.total / this.scores.length : 0;
  }

  resetScore() {
    this.scores = [];
    this.score = 0;
    }

  };
```

And here's my Leaderboard class:

```
class LeaderBoard extends Player {

  add_score = (player_id, score) => {
    if (!this.player_id) {
      var newPlayer = new Player(player_id, score);
      this.player_id = newPlayer;
    } else {
      var average = this.player_id.averageScore();
      return average.toFixed(1);
    }

  };
/*...(additional functions and closing bracket excluded)*/
```

I was expected the averageScore to show as add_score calls on it, but instead I get the reference error - any ideas?

Comment: why are you declaring `add_score` as a class property in LeaderBoard?

Comment: I don't have a good reason why, though I'm guessing it's unnecessary? Also, could I nest the Player class within leaderboard? Not sure what the best approach is

Comment: what you've coded looks all kinds of wrong to be honest ... why would LeaderBoard, presumably a list of Players extend Player? and why would you set this.player_id ... which is an ID in the constructor of Player, to be a Player instance? The code makes very little sense

Comment: also, the only error I get with your code is `this.player_id.averageScore` if I instantiate LeaderBoard with arguments like new LeaderBoard(1,2) and then try to add_score - never get an error that you get

Comment: I thought I would need to `extends Player` to be able to access the functions in Player

Comment: no, you need to instantiate a Player to access the functions in a particular players object

Comment: and that's taken care of with `var newPlayer = new Player...` right?

Comment: no, because your LeaderBoard will only ever have one player ... that's not what I infer from the phrase "Leader Board" :p

Comment: hmmm ... I wonder ... `addScore` in Player and `add_score` in LeaderBoard ... you haven's shown where/how you are calling `add_score` - perhaps it should be `addScore` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense for LeaderBoard to extend Player, since LeaderBoard will contain a list of Players

See code below for working example

```js
class Player {
    constructor(player_id, score) {
        this.player_id = player_id;
        this.scores = [score];
        this.total = score;
        //this.average = this.total/this.scores.length;
    }

    addScore(score) {
        this.total += score;
        this.scores.push(score);
        return score;
    }

    averageScore() {
        return this.scores.length ? this.total / this.scores.length : 0;
    }

    resetScore() {
        this.scores = [];
        this.score = 0;
    }

};
class LeaderBoard {
    constructor() {
        this.players = {};
    }
    addScore(player_id, score) {
        if (!this.players[player_id]) {
            this.players[player_id] = new Player(player_id, score);
        } else {
            this.players[player_id].addScore(score);
        }
        var average = this.players[player_id].averageScore();
        return average.toFixed(1);
    }
};
let x = new LeaderBoard();
console.log(x.addScore(1, 1)); // avg is 1 / 1 === 1
console.log(x.addScore(1, 3)); // avg is (1 + 3) / 2 === 2
console.log(x.addScore(1, 5)); // avg is (1 + 3 + 5) / 3 === 3
console.log(x.addScore(2, 7)); // avg for player 2 is 7 / 1 === 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of defining it as normally. Here is the code that should be used for the `LeaderBoard` class:

```js
class LeaderBoard extends Player {

  add_score(player_id, score) { //THIS LINE IS WHERE YOU WENT WRONG
    if (!this.player_id) {
      var newPlayer = new Player(player_id, score);
      this.player_id = newPlayer;
    } else {
      var average = this.player_id.averageScore();
      return average.toFixed(1);
    }

  };
/*...(additional functions and closing bracket excluded)*/
```

Comment: the arrow function version works the same as the non arrow in my testing

Comment: In mine, it only works after the i change the arrow to non-arrow

Comment: I presume OP uses babel with stage-3 preset enabled - otherwise the error would be completely different